# How can I find out parent folder id and content modified in my box cloud?

Tags: java, boxapiv2

How can I find the parent folder `id` and content modified in my box cloud?

When I use this:

```
fileInfo.getContentModifiedAt()
```

and

```
fileInfo.getParent()
```

I get `null`.

API version `v2.1.0`

Comment: I found how to get parent folder id:
BoxFolder folder = new BoxFolder(api, "id of folder who`s parent you want to know");
folder.getInfo().getParent().getName();

Answer (score 0):

The `id of root is 0`, i.e of All Files
To add folder in root directory, add:

```
BoxApiFolder api=new BoxApiFolder(boxSession);
BoxFolder folder=api.getCreateRequest("0"."Your Folder name here");


// get Id of created folder*

String id=folder.getId();
Log.i("id",id);
```